# Change textColor of UINavigationBar "prompt"?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, colors, uinavigationbar

Any (supported) way of doing this? IIRC it usually switches over by itself to a white color at some point when using a "darker than X" tintColor, but we seem to be just on the edge with our scheme.

Comment: This is really annoying as iOS 5 has a method of doing all of this for the title, why not for the prompt too?!

Comment: @hypercrypt it can be done in iOS 5, read my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to really do it is to use a custom `titleView` for each `UINavigationItem`. You can use a `UILabel` and try to match the built-in navigation title style as closely as you can, then assign your own text color.

Comment: Seems there's no sanctioned way anyhow.

Answer (score 11):

It's possible in iOS5:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]];
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not work to set the text of the UINavigationItem's prompt.

Comment: When you set the text with `self.navigationItem.prompt = @"My Prompt"` it will have the custom color, I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

And for iOS 7 you can make this to set the prompt to White Color. Please note that it will also change the color of the navbar title.

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTitleTextAttributes:
  @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```