# iPhone/Objective-C - Change default "navigationItem.prompt" color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to set the `self.navigationItem.prompt` color to White? At the moment it's Black.

This is how I'm setting my navigationBar color at the moment:

```
// Set top navigation bar.
UINavigationBar *bar = [navController navigationBar];
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:180.0/255.0 green:25.0/255.0 blue:34.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
UIImageView *navBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[navBar release];
```

..and this is how I'm setting my `navigationItem.prompt`:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Tap image for more options.";
```

Comment: what do you mean by navigationBar.prompt?

Comment: navigationItem.prompt not navigationBar.prompt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change textColor of UINavigationBar "prompt"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491345/change-textcolor-of-uinavigationbar-prompt)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Swift:

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
                 [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: At least in iOS 11 prompt color is still black

Comment: its changing only the Navigation's Title color

Answer (score 7):

Its possible now in iOS 5 or later. Try this code.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]];
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that the prompt color is hardcoded and not customizable.

I managed to customize the prompt using the following (tricky) hack, that replace the prompt :

- Set the `navigationItem.prompt = @""` to force the navigationBar to display an empty prompt
- Set the `navigationItem.titleView` with :

  - A `UILabel` or whatever you want to replace title, with inside, as a subView, to replace the prompt :

    - Another *UILabel* as prompt, styled as you like
    - That label being x centered and with a y=-31px offset (that's where normal prompt is)
    - Make sure that the titleView has `.clipsToBounds = NO` so the custom prompt is drawed properly

I applied this for all my controllers by overriding `UIViewController.setTitle:` with something like *(that won't work/build as is, it is a quick extraction of a more complex code, but that shows the logic)* :

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title {
  [super setTitle:title];
  UILabel *titleLabel = ... build the titleLabel
  titleLabel.text = title;
  if (self.navigationItem.prompt) {
    UILabel *promptLabel = ... build the promptLabel
    promptLabel.text = self.navigationItem.prompt;
    self.navigationItem.prompt = @"";
    promptLabel.centerX = titleLabel.width/2;
    promptLabel.top = -31;
    [titleLabel addSubview:promptLabel];
    titleLabel.clipsToBounds = NO;
  }
  self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: How would this work if we just tried to override setPrompt in a category for UINavigationItem? I can't seem to get it to work. I want to show the prompt when some button is pressed, not always.

Comment: From memory (I might be wrong) prompt is only loaded when controller is pushed in the navigationController, then setting the navigation item.prompt after has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In iOs 5 I changed with appearance of UINavigationBar. You can change color of prompt with following code

```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor colorWithRed:10 green:20 blue:30 alpha:1.0f], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil]];
```

I used to random number & colors, You can customize colors by passing your own choice. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

`navigationhBar.tintColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4039216041564941 green:0.6470588445663452 blue:0.062745101749897 alpha:1];`

Comment: First of all, that makes the navigationBar a green color and second of all the text is still black. What I requested was the navigationBar to stay Red and change the navigationBar.prompt color to White.

Comment: I have already set it to Red using RGB. But the navigationBar.prompt color is still Black and I want it to be White. Please read my question again if you're unsure of what I am after.

Comment: UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lbl setText:@"First View"];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[navigationBar topItem].titleView = lbl;
[lbl release];

Comment: No, that's still not what I am after.