# How to change text color of status bar prompt?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4, ios4

Is there any possibility to change the text color of navigation bar prompt (i.e. the area with optional instructions) in Cocoa Touch? The text can be changed using this

```
[self.navigationItem setPrompt:@"My Prompt"];
```

but what about the color of this text? Thanks.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827214/iphone-objective-c-change-default-navigationitem-prompt-color

Comment: Yeah, this is the same issue. I was not able to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a UILabel to your navigation and set it's color

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    UILabel *theLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
theLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
theLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
theLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];



    UIView *myLabel = (make a view and add "theLabel" to it)


    UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCutomView:myLabel];
    [self.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem animated:NO]

}
```